# AngularJS and ASP.Net WebAPI Social Login on a Mobile Browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am following this article on Social Logins with AngularJS and ASP.Net WebAPI (which is quite good):

[ASP.NET Web API 2 external logins with Facebook and Google in AngularJS app](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/)

Pretty much, the code works fine when you are running the social login through a desktop browser (i.e. Chrome, FF, IE, Edge). The social login opens in a new window (not tab) and you are able to use either your Google or Facebook account and once your are logged in through any of them, you are redirected to the callback page (authComplete.html), and the callback page has a JS file defined (authComplete.js) that would close the window and execute a command on the parent window.

the angularJS controller which calls the external login url and opens a popup window (not tab) on desktop browsers:

**loginController.js**

```
'use strict';
app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$location', 'authService', 'ngAuthSettings', function ($scope, $location, authService, ngAuthSettings) {

    $scope.loginData = {
        userName: "",
        password: "",
        useRefreshTokens: false
    };

    $scope.message = "";

    $scope.login = function () {

        authService.login($scope.loginData).then(function (response) {

            $location.path('/orders');

        },
         function (err) {
             $scope.message = err.error_description;
         });
    };

    $scope.authExternalProvider = function (provider) {

        var redirectUri = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/authcomplete.html';

        var externalProviderUrl = ngAuthSettings.apiServiceBaseUri + "api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=" + provider
                                                                    + "&response_type=token&client_id=" + ngAuthSettings.clientId
                                                                    + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri;
        window.$windowScope = $scope;

        var oauthWindow = window.open(externalProviderUrl, "Authenticate Account", "location=0,status=0,width=600,height=750");
    };

    $scope.authCompletedCB = function (fragment) {

        $scope.$apply(function () {

            if (fragment.haslocalaccount == 'False') {

                authService.logOut();

                authService.externalAuthData = {
                    provider: fragment.provider,
                    userName: fragment.external_user_name,
                    externalAccessToken: fragment.external_access_token
                };

                $location.path('/associate');

            }
            else {
                //Obtain access token and redirect to orders
                var externalData = { provider: fragment.provider, externalAccessToken: fragment.external_access_token };
                authService.obtainAccessToken(externalData).then(function (response) {

                    $location.path('/orders');

                },
             function (err) {
                 $scope.message = err.error_description;
             });
            }

        });
    }
}]);
```

**authComplete.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <script src="scripts/authComplete.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**authComplete.js**

```
window.common = (function () {
    var common = {};

    common.getFragment = function getFragment() {
        if (window.location.hash.indexOf("#") === 0) {
            return parseQueryString(window.location.hash.substr(1));
        } else {
            return {};
        }
    };

    function parseQueryString(queryString) {
        var data = {},
            pairs, pair, separatorIndex, escapedKey, escapedValue, key, value;

        if (queryString === null) {
            return data;
        }

        pairs = queryString.split("&");

        for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
            pair = pairs[i];
            separatorIndex = pair.indexOf("=");

            if (separatorIndex === -1) {
                escapedKey = pair;
                escapedValue = null;
            } else {
                escapedKey = pair.substr(0, separatorIndex);
                escapedValue = pair.substr(separatorIndex + 1);
            }

            key = decodeURIComponent(escapedKey);
            value = decodeURIComponent(escapedValue);

            data[key] = value;
        }

        return data;
    }

    return common;
})();

var fragment = common.getFragment();
window.location.hash = fragment.state || '';
window.opener.$windowScope.authCompletedCB(fragment);
window.close();
```

The issue I am having is that when I run the application on a mobile device (Safari, Chrome for Mobile), the social login window opens in a new tab and the JS function which was intended to pass back the fragment to the main application window does not execute nad the new tab does not close.

You can actually try this behavior on both a desktop and mobile browser through the application:

http://ngauthenticationapi.azurewebsites.net/

What I have tried so far in this context is in the login controller, I modified the function so that the external login url opens in the same window:

```
$scope.authExternalProvider = function (provider) {
        var redirectUri = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/authcomplete.html';
        var externalProviderUrl = ngAuthSettings.apiServiceBaseUri + "api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=" + provider
                                                                                                                                + "&response_type=token&client_id=" + ngAuthSettings.clientId
                                                                                                                                + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri;
        window.location = externalProviderUrl;
};
```

And modified the authComplete.js common.getFragment function to return to the login page, by appending the access token provided by the social login as query string:

```
common.getFragment = function getFragment() {
        if (window.location.hash.indexOf("#") === 0) {
                var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
                var redirectUrl = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/#/login?ext=' + hash;
                window.location = redirectUrl;
        } else {
                return {};
        }
};
```

And in the login controller, I added a function to parse the querystring and try to call the $scope.authCompletedCB(fragment) function like:

```
var vm = this;
var fragment = null;

vm.testFn = function (fragment) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {

                if (fragment.haslocalaccount == 'False') {

                        authenticationService.logOut();

                        authenticationService.externalAuthData = {
                                provider: fragment.provider,
                                userName: fragment.external_user_name,
                                externalAccessToken: fragment.external_access_token
                        };

                        $location.path('/associate');

                }
                else {
                        //Obtain access token and redirect to orders
                        var externalData = { provider: fragment.provider, externalAccessToken: fragment.external_access_token };
                        authenticationService.obtainAccessToken(externalData).then(function (response) {

                                $location.path('/home');

                        },
                 function (err) {
                         $scope.message = err.error_description;
                 });
                }

        });
}

init();

function parseQueryString(queryString) {
        var data = {},
                pairs, pair, separatorIndex, escapedKey, escapedValue, key, value;

        if (queryString === null) {
                return data;
        }

        pairs = queryString.split("&");

        for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
                pair = pairs[i];
                separatorIndex = pair.indexOf("=");

                if (separatorIndex === -1) {
                        escapedKey = pair;
                        escapedValue = null;
                } else {
                        escapedKey = pair.substr(0, separatorIndex);
                        escapedValue = pair.substr(separatorIndex + 1);
                }

                key = decodeURIComponent(escapedKey);
                value = decodeURIComponent(escapedValue);

                data[key] = value;
        }

        return data;
}

function init() {
        var idx = window.location.hash.indexOf("ext=");

        if (window.location.hash.indexOf("#") === 0) {
                fragment = parseQueryString(window.location.hash.substr(idx));
                vm.testFn(fragment);
        }
}
```

But obviously this is giving me an error related to angular (which I have no clue at the moment):

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$digest

So, pretty much it is a dead end for me at this stage.

Any ideas or input would be highly appreciated.

Gracias!

Update: I managed to resolve the Angular error about the rootscope being thrown, but sadly, resolving that does not fix the main issue. If I tried to open the social login on the same browser tab where my application is, Google can login and return to the application and pass the tokens required. It is a different story for Facebook, where in the Developer's tools console, there is a warning that seems to stop Facebook from displaying the login page.

Pretty much, the original method with which a new window (or tab) is opened is the way forward but fixing the same for mobile browser seems to be getting more challenging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On desktop, when the auth window pops up (not tab) it has the `opener` property set to the window which opened this pop up window, on mobile, as you said, its not a pop up window but a new tab. when a new tab is opened in the browser, the `opener` property is `null` so actually you have an exception here:

`window.opener.$windowScope.authCompletedCB`

because you can't refer the `$windowScope` property of the null value (`window.opener`) so every line of code after this one wont be executed - thats why the window isn't closed on mobile.

**A Solution**

In your `authComplete.js` file, instead of trying to call
`window.opener.$windowScope.authCompletedCB` and pass the fragment of the user, save the fragment in the localStorage or in a cookie (after all the page at `authComplete.html` is in the same origin as your application) using `JSON.stringify()` and just close the window using `window.close()`.

In the `loginController.js`, make an `$interval` for something like 100ms to check for a value in the localStorage or in a cookie (don't forget to clear the interval when the `$scope` is `$destroy`), if afragment exist you can parse its value using `JSON.parse` from the storage, remove it from the storage and call `$scope.authCompletedCB` with the parsed value.

**UPDATE - Added code samples**

**authComplete.js**

```
...
var fragment = common.getFragment();
// window.location.hash = fragment.state || '';
// window.opener.$windowScope.authCompletedCB(fragment);
localStorage.setItem("auth_fragment", JSON.stringify(fragment))
window.close();
```

**loginController.js**

```
app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$interval', '$location', 'authService', 'ngAuthSettings',
function ($scope, $interval, $location, authService, ngAuthSettings) {

    ...

    // check for fragment every 100ms
    var _interval = $interval(_checkForFragment, 100);

    function _checkForFragment() {
        var fragment = localStorage.getItem("auth_fragment");
        if(fragment && (fragment = JSON.parse(fragment))) {

            // clear the fragment from the storage
            localStorage.removeItem("auth_fragment");

            // continue as usual
            $scope.authCompletedCB(fragment);

            // stop looking for fragmet
            _clearInterval();
        }
    }

    function _clearInterval() {
        $interval.cancel(_interval);
    }

    $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
        // clear the interval when $scope is destroyed
        _clearInterval();
    });

}]);
```

Comment: I would take time to test this out later on the day.

Comment: You don't need to, the `localStorage` is part of the HTML5 API in the browser, actually its on the `window`, you can access it from anywhere using `window.localStorage`

Comment: Just tried this out now and I am getting some rootscope error Error: $rootScope:inprog
Action Already In Progress

Comment: Remove the $rootScope.$apply from authCompletedCB

Comment: Just a few more. Getting some JS errors: TypeError: _interval.cancel is not a function

Comment: you are right, I updated the `_clearInterval` function to -> `$interval.cancel(_interval);`